# Import-CSV for Active Directory Object Already Exists Error

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I created a PowerShell script to import new AD users from a CSV file. The code is:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$Users = Import-Csv -Delimiter "," -Path "C:\temp\kindergarten.csv"
$Password = 000
foreach ($User in $Users) {
    $Password = $Password + 1
    $OU = "OU=KCenter,OU=Students,OU=District Users New,DC=,DC=k12,DC=ny,DC=us"
    $UserFirstname = $User.FirstName
    $UserLastname = $User.LastName
    $DetailedName = $UserFirstname + " " + $UserLastname
    $FirstLetterFirstname = $UserFirstname.substring(0,1)
    $SAMName = $FirstLetterFirstname + $UserLastname
    $UserPrincipalName = $SAMName + "@student.pobschools.org"
    $Description = "Kindergarteners K-Center"


    New-ADUser -Name $DetailedName -SamAccountName $SAMName -UserPrincipalName $UserPrincipalName -DisplayName     
    $SAMName -GivenName $UserFirstname -Surname $UserLastname -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force) 
    -Enabled $false -Description $Description -EmailAddress $UserPrincipalName -CannotChangePassword $true -ChangePasswordAtLogon $false -Path $OU
    }
```

The script worked for about half of the entries in the CSV. For the others I get the error:

```
New-ADUser : The object already exists
At C:\users\jbaruch\desktop\getADUsers.ps1:16 char:12
+     New-ADUser <<<<  -Name $DetailedName -SamAccountName $SAMName -UserPrincipalName $UserPrincipalName -DisplayName
$SAMName -GivenName $UserFirstname -Surname $UserLastname -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainTe
xt -Force) -Enabled $false -Description $Description -EmailAddress $UserPrincipalName -CannotChangePassword $true -Chan
gePasswordAtLogon $false -Path $OU
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (CN=Shradha Sang...k12,DC=ny,DC=us:String) [New-ADUser], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : The object already exists,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADUser
```

If I search for the users I get an error for there are no results. I am not sure why it is coming back as already existing. Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: I thought I had checked already, but it looks like the users that failed have the same SAM name as another account. I would like to modify my script to check if the SAM name exists and if it does to add the second letter of their first name before their last name in the SAM name. Can I do this with a simple if statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading your comment I think this might help you:

```
$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'

$Users = Import-Csv -Delimiter "," -Path "C:\temp\kindergarten.csv"
$Password = 000
foreach ($User in $Users) {

    $Password = $Password + 1
    $SamAccountName = $User.FirstName[0] + $User.LastName

    if ($U = Get-ADUser -Filter {SamAccountName -eq $SamAccountName}) {
        Write-Verbose "SamAccountName $($SamAccountName) already present"

        if ($U.GivenName -eq $User.FirstName) {
            Write-Verbose "User firstname $($User.FirstName) already present in AD"
            Continue # to the next user
        }
        $SamAccountName = $User.FirstName[1] + $User.LastName
        Write-Verbose "New SamAccountName generated $($SamAccountName)"
    }

    $ADParams = @{
        Name                  = $UserFirstname + ' ' + $UserLastname
        SamAccountName        = $SamAccountName
        UserPrincipalName     = $SamAccountName + '@student.pobschools.org'
        DisplayName           = $SamAccountName
        GivenName             = $User.FirstName
        Surname               = $User.LastName
        AccountPassword       = (ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force)
        Enabled               = $false
        Description           = 'Kindergarteners K-Center'
        EmailAddress          = $SamAccountName + '@student.pobschools.org'
        CannotChangePassword  = $true
        ChangePasswordAtLogon = $false
        Path                  = 'OU=KCenter,OU=Students,OU=District Users New,DC=,DC=k12,DC=ny,DC=us'
    }
    Write-Verbose "Create user $($SamAccountName)"
    New-ADUser @ADParams
}
```

Splatting is a nice technique for this to make things more readable.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that looks great. Only thing is that if I run the same csv file then all the items that were previously added are added again with a new SAM account name. I would think I'd need to check if it exists and then check if the first name is the same. If the first name is also the same then I do not want the user to be created. I will try to do this with a nested if statement after the other one. Or should I use an AND && in the filter?

Comment: I improved the code to check if the user with the same `SamAccountName` also has the same `FirstName`. I hope to show you some techniques which you can use in the future. The more you play with PowerShell the better you'll get at it :) If it's ok for you don't forget to mark the question as solved.