# How to catch errors from powershell and write them on a .txt file?

Tags: c#, powershell

I am using a script to update the data of Active Directory users

```
Import-Csv -Path $Path | foreach-object {Set-ADUser -Identity ($_.user) -Department $_.Department -Title $_.Title -Company $_.Company -MobilePhone $_.MobilePhone ...etc (the required data to modify)}
```

I want the script to write the errors in the update of an "x" user's, to see whose user wasn't updated.

I'm creating a C# app to write a personalized script, and still need to make the error log.

The idea is to create this log in a specified path. I don't know if this can be made in the script it self.

I'm using this PowerShell method I have found here:

```
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.AddScript(script);

IAsyncResult result = ps.BeginInvoke();

// do something else until execution has completed.
// this could be sleep/wait, or perhaps some other work
while (result.IsCompleted == false)
{
  //think i can make that here, but can´t see how
}   
MessageBox.Show("Complete");
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell.streams?view=pscore-6.2.0#System_Management_Automation_PowerShell_Streams - Grab the error stream

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import-CSV for Active Directory Object Already Exists Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32377668/import-csv-for-active-directory-object-already-exists-error)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please ensure to ask clear questions.  I'm not sure if you are asking how to log errors in powershell or c#

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this can be used to get you going quickly.  Without seeing the script, i'll have to simply assume that you have a ps1 file, and you want the errors it generates:

```
.\myhugescript.ps1 | Out-File -Path D:\log.log -Append
$(.\myhugescript.ps1) | Out-File -Path D:\log.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write errors to a file like this:

```
$logFilePath = "..."
Import-Csv -Path $Path | foreach-object {
    Try {
        $user = $_.user
        Set-ADUser -Identity $user -Department $_.Department -Title $_.Title -Company $_.Company -MobilePhone $_.MobilePhone ...etc (the required data to modify)
    } Catch [system.exception] {
        $t = get-date -format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        $msg = "$t -- Error updating user $user: $($_.Exception.Message)`n"
        $msg | Out-File -Append $logFilePath
    }
}
```

You could also replace `Out-File` with `Write-Error` to write to the stderr stream and then read that stream directly in the C# code, to save the disk I/O. There's an example of what that looks like here:

> [Get Powershell command's output when invoked through code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34398023/3043)

Replace the `Progress` stream in that example with the `Error` stream.